# setOnClickPendingIntent in notification doesn't work on android N? Detail: It needs click twice?why?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

code:

```
intent = new Intent(ACTION_STOP);
intent.setClass(context, SoundRecorderService.class);
pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
mNotificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_stop, pIntent);

Notification.Builder builder=new Notification.Builder(context);
Notification notification = builder.build();
notification.contentView = mNotificationView;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

notification.icon = R.drawable.notification_ic_small;
notification.contentIntent = pIntent;
startForeground(START_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

These codes do well in `android M`. But it performs abnormally in `android N`. When we first click `btn_stop` button, the phone systems doesn't send this `PendingIntent`, so it doesn't start  `SoundRecorderService.class`. Then we click on it again, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! My notification remoteview layout fix one point, error code:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_stop"
            android:layout_width="17dp"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/notification_background"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:src="@drawable/notification_stop"
```

android:focusableInTouchMode="true" fix to android:clickable="true" correct code:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_stop"
            android:layout_width="17dp"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/notification_stop" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug is clearly visible on the emulator, where you can do any number of clicks on the same point. The essence of the bug is that clicks are periodically lost in the area of custom notification. These code do well in Android L, M and O.

Example of simple layout with not working clicks if the height for the ImageButton is set to "match_parent". The solution that worked for me was to set a specific value for height ("64dp").

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  tools:layout_height="64dp">

  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/button_1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_notify_1"/>
  </FrameLayout>      
</LinearLayout>
```